# how to import data from mysql database to datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, mysql-workbench

i have a table in mysql database named cms.order
and i am working on a widows form using C#.
How can i show the data from the table in database in the datagridview of the windows form

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code to read the table data from database and display it into data gridview.

```
string connectionString = ""; //Set your MySQL connection string here.
string query =""; // set query to fetch data "Select * from  tabelname"; 
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        DataGridView1.DataSource= ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: just in case anyone is using wpf instead of winforms, do the following: datagrid1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; - and then in the xaml for the datagrid, add ItemsSource="{Binding}"

Answer (score 0):

With a simple search on the internet you can find a simple solution...

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable

---

From youtube, you can also get this information

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peiorDq5oF0

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0bRgwuUNUg

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm5mxkytfWk

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlConnection con= new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=databasename;user=username;password=password");

string query="select *from table";

using (MySqlDataAdapter adpt= new MySqlDataAdapter(query,con))
{

DataSet dset= new DataSet();

adpt.Fill(dset);

mytableDataGridView.DataSource=dset.Tables[0];

}
con.close
```