# Call Data from MySql Database in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to view data from my database using the datagridview, what possible code can i use:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

End Sub
```

I'm using VB for the code.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please add your attempts and research to the question. Follow the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of answers regarding this task here on the StackOverflow and also else where. Here is one example [how to import data from mysql database to datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132596/how-to-import-data-from-mysql-database-to-datagridview).

But why are you trying to use `CellContentClick`? Do you want to load data when a cell is clicked? Be aware, this event will *only* work if you click cell's content, i.e. the text. If you miss the text (content), it won't be fired. For a [whole] cell click, use `CellClick`. But perhaps you're lost and want something absolutely different, like run it from a button. It's difficult to tell, if you don't provide enough information.